# Building Hadoop(1.2.1) Eclipse(Kepler 4.3.1) Plugin

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I tried building an eclipse plugin for Hadoop for my Eclipse Kepler V 4.3.1
In the web I see a lot of information for JUNO and some prior versions but tried copying those jars into my eclipse->plugin directory brought me no luck. hence tried building my own eclipse plugin but even that is not working for me. Has anyone here has a Hadoop plugin working for Kepler?
Below are my other config details :
Mac OSX
java version "1.6.0_65"

Comment: I was able to get the plug in generated and working with Eclipse Juno but still no luck with Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sucessfully build it using [this guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yuZ4IjlquPkmC1zXtCeL4GUNKT1uY1xnS_SCBJHps6A/edit?pli=1)
with some slight modifications, i am however using Eclipse 4.3.2 on Arch and java 7.

Either way here is [my plugin](https://spideroak.com/share/OB2WE3DJMNPXG5DVMZTA/so_stuff/home/jacob/SpiderOak%20Hive/public_stuff/hadoop-eclipse-plugin-1.2.1.jar) if it helps.